# RTK Query manual cache update for endpoint where query key is generated through serialization method

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

We have Two RTK query where one is get query which save data in cache using serialization method and other mutation where on successful update at backend we want to update the cache manually in frontend.. But while applying patch inside onQueryStarted of mutation, updateQueryData is not able to catch the query key of cache generated through serialization method..

Get query Function:-

```
   getdataByUserId: builder.query({   
          query: ({userProfileId,cursor, limit}) => ({  
              url:/data/${userProfileId}?cursor=${cursor}&limit=${limit},     
               method: 'GET', 
                validateStatus: (response, result) => {         
            return response.status === 200 && !result.isError   
              },             }),        
         serializeQueryArgs: ({queryArgs,endpointDefinition, endpointName }) => {       
                      if (queryArgs){                
                 const cache = queryArgs;         
                        const userProfileId = cache.userProfileId; 
                                return getdataByUserId("${userProfileId}")`; } },
         transformResponse: responseData => { 
                    },
        merge: (currentCache, newItems) => {
            console.log("currentCache",currentCache,newItems);

            if (!newItems) {
                return currentCache;
            }

            if (currentCache ) {
              const newEntities = newItems.entities;
              const currentEntities = currentCache.entities;
              const updatedEntities = { ...currentEntities };
              Object.keys(newEntities).forEach((key) => {
                if (!currentEntities[key]) {
                  updatedEntities[key] = newEntities[key];
                }
              });
              const newIds = newItems.ids.filter((id) => !currentEntities[id]);
              const updatedIds = [...currentCache.ids, ...newIds];
              const updatedCache = { ...currentCache, entities: updatedEntities, ids: updatedIds };
              return updatedCache;
            } else {
              return dataAdapter.setAll(initialState, newItems);
            }
          },
        providesTags: (result, error, arg) => {
            if (result?.ids) {
                    ]
            } else return [{ type: 'dataByUSerId', id: 'LIST' }]
        },
    }),
```

`

below is the mutation function which is common for function to update data where data is called by getalldata or getdataByUserId where patchResult handles first and patchResult_1 handles later..

```
       updatedata: builder.mutation({      
       query: ({ userId, dataId,dataUserId, reactionType, }) => ({    
             url:datas/${dataId},                
             method: 'PATCH',             
            body: {reactionType : reactionType}             }),  
               async onQueryStarted({ userId, dataId, dataUserId,reactionType }, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {   
                    const userProfileId = dataUserId;  
                    const dataIdd = dataId;         
                    const reactionTypee = reactionType;     
                    const userIdd = userId;              
                    const patchResult = dispatch(                       
                                            datasApiSlice.util.updateQueryData('getdatas', undefined, draft => {

                    const patchResult_1 = dispatch(
                    // datasApiSlice.util.updateQueryData(`getdatasByUserId("${userProfileId}")`,  draft => {
                    datasApiSlice.util.updateQueryData('getdatasByUserId',userProfileId , draft => {
                    // Update the cache data optimistically for the user's datas
                    console.log('drafttttttt',arguments, draft)
                    const data = draft.data[dataId];
                    console.log("patchResult_1",data);
```

## issue is with line

```
 datasApiSlice.util.updateQueryData('getdatasByUserId',userProfileId , draft
```

## of patchResult_1  which is not able to recognise the cachequery key in cahce data to process it further which is depend on getdataByUserId query function.. Thanks in advance to solve this challenging issue.